# How to rearrange Pandas column sequence?

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df =DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,4,6,8]})
>>> df['x']=df.a + df.b
>>> df['y']=df.a - df.b
>>> df
   a  b   x  y
0  1  2   3 -1
1  2  4   6 -2
2  3  6   9 -3
3  4  8  12 -4
```

Now I want to rearrange the column sequence, which makes 'x','y' column to be the first & second columns by :

```
>>> df = df[['x','y','a','b']]
>>> df
    x  y  a  b
0   3 -1  1  2
1   6 -2  2  4
2   9 -3  3  6
3  12 -4  4  8
```

But if I have a long coulmns 'a','b','c','d'....., and I don't want to explictly list the columns. How can I do that ?

Or Does Pandas provide a function like `set_column_sequence(dataframe,col_name, seq)` so that I can do  :  `set_column_sequence(df,'x',0)` and `set_column_sequence(df,'y',1)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def _col_seq_set(df, col_list, seq_list):
    ''' set dataframe 'df' col_list's sequence by seq_list '''
    col_not_in_col_list = [x for x in list(df.columns) if x not in col_list]
    for i in range(len(col_list)):
        col_not_in_col_list.insert(seq_list[i], col_list[i])

    return df[col_not_in_col_list]
DataFrame.col_seq_set = _col_seq_set
```

Answer (score 50):

You could also do something like this:

```
df = df[['x', 'y', 'a', 'b']]
```

You can get the list of columns with:

```
cols = list(df.columns.values)
```

The output will produce something like this:

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y']
```

...which is then easy to rearrange manually before dropping it into the first function

Comment: For newbies like me, re-arrange the `list` you get from `cols`. Then `df=df[cols]` i.e. the re-arranged list gets dropped into the first expression without only one set of brackets.

Comment: Could you be explaining the first example?

Answer (score 12):

There may be an elegant built-in function (but I haven't found it yet). You could write one:

```
# reorder columns
def set_column_sequence(dataframe, seq, front=True):
    '''Takes a dataframe and a subsequence of its columns,
       returns dataframe with seq as first columns if "front" is True,
       and seq as last columns if "front" is False.
    '''
    cols = seq[:] # copy so we don't mutate seq
    for x in dataframe.columns:
        if x not in cols:
            if front: #we want "seq" to be in the front
                #so append current column to the end of the list
                cols.append(x)
            else:
                #we want "seq" to be last, so insert this
                #column in the front of the new column list
                #"cols" we are building:
                cols.insert(0, x)
return dataframe[cols]
```

*For your example: `set_column_sequence(df, ['x','y'])` would return the desired output.*

If you want the seq at the *end* of the DataFrame instead simply pass in "front=False".

Comment: Hopefully I can find Pandas build-in 'set_column_sequence(df, col_list, assign_col_seq)' function, that I can use "set_column_sequence(df,['x','y'],[0,1])" to have the job done.

Comment: @bigbug Hopefully! If I find one I'll update my answer... 'til you do, this should work.

Comment: How about including a list comprehension version to speed it up?

Comment: @pylang I don't think that'll speed it up (that's not the main perf issue I shouldn't think) but a neat way to write it is: `s = {col: i for i, col in enumerate(first_cols)}; sorted(df.columns, key=lambda c: s.get(c, len(s)))`. This is still (4 years later) kinda awkward to write, I though perhaps there was a trick with sort_index, but there doesn't seem to be. hmmm

Comment: @pylang potentially you can do: `df[df.columns[df.columns.map(lambda col: s.get(col, len(s))).argsort()]]` but that;s pretty ugly. Still better than this old answer, so I may edit that in...

Answer (score 7):

You can do the following:

```
df =DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,4,6,8]})

df['x']=df.a + df.b
df['y']=df.a - df.b
```

create column title whatever order you want in this way:

```
column_titles = ['x','y','a','b']

df.reindex(columns=column_titles)
```

This will give you desired output

Comment: My preferred way because this can be chained with other methods on the dataframe

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you just write a function to do what you're saying probably using `drop` (to delete columns) and `insert` to insert columns at a position. There isn't an existing API function to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to disregard this solution as subtracting a list from an Index does not preserve the order of the original Index, if that's important.

```
In [61]: df.reindex(columns=pd.Index(['x', 'y']).append(df.columns - ['x', 'y']))
Out[61]: 
    x  y  a  b
0   3 -1  1  2
1   6 -2  2  4
2   9 -3  3  6
3  12 -4  4  8
```