# Using Pandas to concatenate CSV files in directory, recursively

Tags: python, csv, pandas, merge, concatenation

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335474/merging-multiple-csv-files-without-headers-being-repeated-using-python) from a previous post. I am citing [P.R.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2156909/p-r) response below.

```
 import pandas as pd
    import glob
    interesting_files = glob.glob("*.csv")
    df_list = []
    for filename in sorted(interesting_files):
        df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
    full_df = pd.concat(df_list)

    full_df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

I am wondering how to modify the above, using pandas. Specifically, I am attempting to recursively move through a directory and concatenate all of the CSV headers and their respective row values and then write it out in one file. Using P.R's approach, results in all of the headers and their corresponding values being stacked upon each other. My constraints are:

- Writing out the headers and their corresponding values (without "stacking") - essentially concatenated one after the other
- If the column headers in one file match another files then their should be no repetition. Only the values should be appended as they are written to the one CSV file.
- Since each file has different column headers and different number of column headers these should all be added. Nothing should be deleted.

I have tried the following as well:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import glob
import os

path = '.'
files_in_dir = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('csv')]

for filenames in files_in_dir:
    df = pd.read_csv(filenames)
    df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a')
```

Here are two sample CSV:

```
ID,Type,ACH,SH,LL,SS,LS,ISO,MID,Pass,TID,CID,TErrors
12821767,Query,,,,,,,,,,,
```

and

```
Type,ID,CC,CCD,Message,MemberIdentifier,NPass,UHB,UAP,NewAudioPIN,AType,ASuufix,Member,Share,Note,Flag,Card,MA,Preference,ETF,AutoT,RType,Locator,ISO,MID,Pass,TID,CID,Errors
UMember,12822909,True,10/31/2013 5:22:19 AM,,,,False,False,,,,,,,,,,,,,Member,,,,,,,
```

Based on the above to exemplars, the output should be something along the lines of:

```
    ID,Type,ACH,SH,LL,SS,LS,ISO,MID,Pass,TID,CID,TErrors,CC,CCD,Message,MemberIdentifier,NPass,UHB,UAP,NewAudioPIN,AType,ASuufix,Member,Share,Note,Flag,Card,MA,Preference,ETF,AutoT,RType,Locator,Errors
12822909,UMember,,,,,,,,,,,,True,10/31/2013 5:22:19 AM,,,,False,False,,,,,,,,,,,,,Member,,
12821767,Query ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, etc.
```

(all of the header columns in the second sample should be filled in with the delimiter ',' for the second row where there is no corresponding header in the first sample)

As one, can see, the second sample has more column headers. Moreover some of the
headers are the same (but in different order). I am trying to combine all of
these - along with their values, following the above requirements. I am
wondering if the best method is to merge or perform a customizable function on a
built-in method of pandas?

Comment: For the example you posted, what is the desired result?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to use `pandas` here - I'd imagine it'd be easier without it... (interesting new name @HappyLeapSecond!)

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond I have tried to make this clear with the bullet points - it is rather hard to explain without drawing it out. All of the headers should be in one "row"/"line" and the values in the subsequent "line". The common headers should not repeat, but the values should be added corresponding to each header. Order should be maintained and no header or value should be deleted. Any new headers should be automatically added (along with its value).

Comment: @JonClements I thought that pandas would be the most efficient method. If  you have alternative suggestion, I welcome your thoughts.

Comment: @890319ahlusar is there just a single data row per CSV file?

Comment: @JonClements  Yes. One row for the headers and one row for the data

Comment: Would a While loop work better than recursion?

Answer (score 1):

A non `pandas` based approach that uses an `OrderedDict` and the `csv` module.

```
from glob import iglob
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

files = sorted(iglob('*.csv'))
header = OrderedDict()
data = []
for filename in files:
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fin:
        csvin = csv.DictReader(fin)
        try:
            header.update(OrderedDict.fromkeys(csvin.fieldnames))
            data.append(next(csvin))
        except TypeError:
            print filename, 'was empty'
        except StopIteration:
            print filename, "didn't contain a row"

with open('output_filename.csv', 'wb') as fout:
    csvout = csv.DictWriter(fout, fieldnames=list(header))
    csvout.writeheader()
    csvout.writerows(data)
```

Given your example input, this gives you:

```
ID,Type,ACH,SH,LL,SS,LS,ISO,MID,Pass,TID,CID,TErrors,CC,CCD,Message,MemberIdentifier,NPass,UHB,UAP,NewAudioPIN,AType,ASuufix,Member,Share,Note,Flag,Card,MA,Preference,ETF,AutoT,RType,Locator,Errors
12821767,Query,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
12822909,UMember,,,,,,,,,,,,True,10/31/2013 5:22:19 AM,,,,False,False,,,,,,,,,,,,,Member,,
```

Comment: I had a very similar solution to your above non-Pandas approach. The caveat is that all of the keys/column names that repeat in other csv files (and have different corresponding row values) are not appended sequentially. For example, in the above two samples, there are two different values for the column header "Type": UMember and Query. Ideally Query should be appended after UMember. If there are other similar column headers, then their values should follow the same rule. The other requirements are still controlled for.

Comment: @890319ahlusar you're really going to have to spend a few moments updating your question with the exact expected output from your input examples then...

Comment: I will do so promptly @JonClements

Comment: @890319ahlusar had to pop out - updated with what I believe to be your requirements...

Comment: @890319ahlusar going to disclose what that error is? :p

Comment: I receive the following error (thank you, again, for your feedback): 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

---> 11         header.update(OrderedDict.fromkeys(csvin.fieldnames))
     12         data.append(next(csvin))

__init__.py in fromkeys(cls, iterable, value)
    220         '''
    221         self = cls()
--> 222         for key in iterable:
    223             self[key] = value
    224         return self

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @890319ahlusar you probably have an empty file then?

Comment: @890319ahlusar wrapped it in a try except so you can see if a file's empty or whether it only contained headers

Comment: You are correct @JonClements - one of the 1134 files was empty! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

In pandas, you can both append column names and reorder the data frame easily. See [this article on merging frames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

To append frames and re-order them you could use the following. Re-indexing is as simple as using a list. There are more solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329853/how-to-rearrange-pandas-column-sequence).

```
import pandas,os

df = None
dfList=[]
for filename in [directory+x for x in os.listdir(path)]:
    dfList.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
df=pandas.concat(dfList)
df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='w')
```

With list comprehension, this would be:

```
import pandas,os    
pandas.concat([pd.read_csv(filename) for filename in [directory+x for x in os.listdir(path) if x.endswith("csv") is True]]).to_csv('out.csv', mode='w')
```

If you want to reindex anything just use a list.

```
cols=sorted(list(df.columns.values))
df=df[cols]
#or
df=df[sorted(list(df.columns.values))]
```

Comment: It would be more performant to read df from each csv into a list and then concat all the dfs in the list rather than concatenating each one

Comment: @EdChum - Is it possible for you to provide an example

Comment: @890319ahlusar reading the article will also explain more complex functions but concat should cover everything

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans Thanks for the reference materials. I have reviewed these thoroughly. However, it appears that one can only merge two data frames at a time. Is there a sub function that you would recommend that allows me to check for the same headers and then append the corresponding value of that header if the check is true? I want to understand the bowels of Pandas :)

Comment: @890319ahlusar Append them in a list like so pandas.concat([df1,df2,df3]). The best example off the bat is at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15819050/pandas-dataframe-concat-vs-append"> this post</a>. I just saw the code. It also goes over append v. concat.

Comment: @AndrewScottEvans I attempted this following your suggestion - it works! Cheers!