# Rearrange columns using column numbers- Pythonic way

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

Rearranging columns in pandas has been asked before in many [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329853/how-to-rearrange-pandas-column-sequence).

I can `print` my columns and copy paste whatever I need to reorder in `pandas`. However, I am wondering if I have more than 20 columns, can I rearrange using columns numbers? I know in `R` this can be done something like this,

```
new_df <- my_df[,c(1:9, 11:21, 10)]
```

I attempted the same below in `pandas`, but getting a `SyntaxError`,

```
new_df = my_df[[:, 1:9, 11:21, 10]]
```

I have been searching and could not find a document to refer to get an answer. Is there anything like that in `pandas` that I can do in one line like in `R`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for concanecate indices:

```
new_df = my_df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:9, 11:21, 10]]
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(100)
my_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,30)))

new_df = my_df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:9, 11:21, 10]]
print (new_df)
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  10
0   8   3   7   7   0   4   2   5   2   1   0   8   4   0   9   6   2   4   2
1   7   0   2   9   9   3   2   5   0   7   6   2   0   8   2   5   1   8   1
2   6   3   4   7   6   3   9   0   5   7   6   6   2   4   2   7   1   6   4
```

---

```
new_df = my_df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:10, 11:22, 10]]
print (new_df)
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   11 ...  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  \
0   8   3   7   7   0   4   2   5   2   2 ...   0   8   4   0   9   6   2   4   
1   7   0   2   9   9   3   2   5   8   0 ...   6   2   0   8   2   5   1   8   
2   6   3   4   7   6   3   9   0   4   5 ...   6   6   2   4   2   7   1   6   

   21  10  
0   1   2  
1   1   1  
2   6   4  

[3 rows x 21 columns]
```

Solution with `range`:

```
a = list(range(1,10)) + list(range(11,22)) + [10]
new_df = my_df.iloc[:, a]
print (new_df)
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   11 ...  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  \
0   8   3   7   7   0   4   2   5   2   2 ...   0   8   4   0   9   6   2   4   
1   7   0   2   9   9   3   2   5   8   0 ...   6   2   0   8   2   5   1   8   
2   6   3   4   7   6   3   9   0   4   5 ...   6   6   2   4   2   7   1   6   

   21  10  
0   1   2  
1   1   1  
2   6   4  

[3 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: it concanecate  indices.

Comment: One thing - `iloc` remove last indices `9`, `21`, do you need it?

Comment: yes, I need the last one too, I was just going to ask

Comment: I add solution for it - simply change 9 to 10 and 21 to 22

Comment: It works like `range` right, I was trying with `range` earlier, but I was missing `np.r_`

Comment: 2 seconds difference ;-)

Answer (score 4):

we can use [np.r_[]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
new_df = my_df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:9, 11:21, 10]]
```

Demo:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(2, 21)))

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  ...  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
0   2   1   2   2   1   0   4   4   4   2 ...   0   4   4   4   3   2   1   2   1   4
1   1   4   4   4   1   3   4   4   3   3 ...   1   2   3   4   2   0   1   0   2   1

[2 rows x 21 columns]

In [9]: df.iloc[:, np.r_[1:9, 11:21, 10]]
Out[9]:
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  10
0   1   2   2   1   0   4   4   4   0   4   4   4   3   2   1   2   1   4   0
1   4   4   4   1   3   4   4   3   1   2   3   4   2   0   1   0   2   1   0
```