# python pandas move few columns to beginning without mentioning other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329853/how-to-rearrange-pandas-column-sequence). In answers of that question i saw few ways to do what i am trying to do below. But answers are old and i feel that there might be a fast and an efficient way to do what i am looking for.

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,4,6,8]})
df['x']=df.a + df.b
df['y']=df.a - df.b
df
   a  b   x  y
0  1  2   3 -1
1  2  4   6 -2
2  3  6   9 -3
3  4  8  12 -4
```

Now I want to move x and y columns to beginning. I can always do below.

```
df = df[['x','y','a','b']]
df
    x  y  a  b
0   3 -1  1  2
1   6 -2  2  4
2   9 -3  3  6
3  12 -4  4  8
```

But I don't want that solution. I want an efficient solution that would move columns x and y to beginning without mentioning names of other columns as my dataframe is going to change and i might not know names of all the columns

Answer (score 1):

You can using `insert`

```
df.insert(loc=0, column='x', value=df.a + df.b)
df.insert(loc=1, column='y', value=df.a - df.b)
df
Out[325]: 
    x  y  a  b
0   3 -1  1  2
1   6 -2  2  4
2   9 -3  3  6
3  12 -4  4  8
```

Comment: is `value=df.a + df.b` part required? I tried `df.insert(loc=0, column='x',value='x')`, but it failed :(. I did it this way because i am reading a csv and my column `x` has static values

Comment: In your example x is calculated by df.a + df.b right ? @Ni_Tempe

Comment: @Ni_Tempe so you have it x, y in another dataframe ?

Comment: no i have a csv file and i am reading that file to create my dataframe

Comment: @Ni_Tempe consider change your question with some sample data , since in your original post we do not get any information about the point you mention in the comment

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df =pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[2,4,6,8]})

a = list(df.columns)

df['x']=df.a + df.b

df['y']=df.a - df.b

b = list(df.columns)

diff = list(set(b) - set(a))

df[diff+a]
df

 y   x  a  b
-1   3  1  2
-2   6  2  4
-3   9  3  6
-4  12  4  8
```

Comment: it wont work as the columns that i want to move could be anywhere in the dataframe...they could be in middle or at the end...

Comment: The columns which you want to move either at the middle or end in the data frame should always be at the beginning ? @Ni_Tempe