# Does changing/rearranging the column order of pandas dataframe create an internal copy?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

While changing order of columns of a pandas dataframe couple of techniques are given.

1. By reassigning the rearranged columns `df = df[['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']]` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23741704/5031718)

or

2. By calling `DataFrame.reindex(columns=neworderlist)` as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47394789/5031718)

The question is whether any of these listed techniques creates copies of the dataframe internally? Is any one of the techniques preferred over the other?
A vague reference is given in pandas [indexing documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) which discourages chained assignments. Does this 'SettingWithCopy' behaviour arise here as well?

Comment: `'SettingWithCopy'` could be tested very simply on your DF, no?

Comment: Good question, there's a [related comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486063/what-is-the-big-o-complexity-of-reversing-the-order-of-columns-in-pandas-datafra#comment90155252_51486063), but I think a good answer will flesh it out.

Comment: By setting `mode.chained_assignment` to `raise` to raise `SettingWithCopyException` exception? I might be wrong.

Comment: @ChadwickRobbert it's a warning that's more common than we would probably like, so your code would just raise it anyway if you tried it. But I agree with jpp that it's a good question :)